# Outlet is nil in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` defined like so:

```
import UIKit

class GalleryCellCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

}
```

Xcode put this in automatically when I added the outlet. In my `UICollectionViewController`'s

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

function, I then try to set an image. My code is

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GalleryCellCollectionViewCell
        let imagePackage = imagePackages?[indexPath.item]
        let uiImage = imagePackage?.getUIImage()
        cell.image.image = uiImage
        return cell
    }
```

In my variable viewer for the debugger, I can see that `uiImage` is not `nil`. However, `cell.image` is `nil`. Why would this be? Did I not link it up correctly in the `storyboard`?

Comment: meaning of this line `let uiImage = imagePackage?.getUIImage()`, show this method.

Comment: `@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!` Never use same variable as it is declared in the apple framework, otherwise x-code get conflict and understands the code according to it.

Comment: As i see your code work, I seems to be perfect, so re-check your `reuseIdentifier ` spelling and whether it is perfectly allocated to the cell `dequeue` property or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can access image with another approach using tag.
from Interface builder (IB) of the cell go to attribute tab (third tab) and set tag for the image (like 5)

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GalleryCellCollectionViewCell
    let imagePackage = imagePackages?[indexPath.item]
    let uiImage = imagePackage?.getUIImage()
    var cellImg:UIImageView = cell!.viewWithTag(5) as! UIImageView;

    cellImg.image = uiImage
    return cell
}
```